# Vuelidate $params set to null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollup, vuelidate

We have a complicated issue with Vue and Vuelidate, basically we've made a Vue component library with Vue and Vuelidate. The library is built with Rollup.

Some components are validated like so:

```
import { maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

...

validations() {
    return {
        value: {
            maxLength: maxLength(4)
        }
    }
}

...
```

This means the number `4` should be available as a param to be used in an error message. This works in the tests in the lib and also in a standalone Vue app that can be run from the lib. `$v.value.$params` is consequently defined as so:

```
{
    maxLength: {
        type: "maxLength",
        max: 4
    }
}
```

The 4 can then be used in an error message, e.g. *"you cannot enter more than 4 characters"*.

However, when the lib is imported to another app, the `$v.value.$params` is set to `null`. Thus the error message becomes: *"you cannot enter more than characters"*.

We've found a couple of issues on this (https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/302, https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/460) but none of the suggested solutions seems to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [my patch](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/pull/850) hasn't been accepted. I couldn't find another way to fix it, so I've now locally patched `vuelidate` to use the patched `withParams.js` file without the conditional:

**lib/webpack/patches/vuelidate-withParams.js**

```js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
   value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;
var withParams = require(__dirname + '/../../../node_modules/vuelidate/lib/params').withParams;
var _default = withParams;
exports.default = _default;
```

**webpack config**

```js
{
   plugins: [
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
         /vuelidate\/lib\/withParams\.js/,
         path.resolve(config.basePath, 'lib/webpack/patches/vuelidate-withParams.js')
      ),
   ],
   /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround when using webpack is setting the BUILD environment variable to `web` in the webpack config.

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      // https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/874
      BUILD: "web",
    }),
  ],
};
```